# Facebook Graph Api: How to disable transliteration from Cyrillic to Latin when querying FB Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When searching with Facebook Graph API for posts containing a phrase in Cyrillic, it returns results containing the transliterated string.

For example when trying to get results for *"стол"*:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=стол&type=post&...
```

I'm getting results for the transliterated string *"stol"*.

**Been there done that:**

1. An old solution was to use the **locale** parameter. As it seems it is not working anymore in this kind of searches "by design".
2. Another proposed solution was to send Accept-Language headers with the query, but doesn't work either.
3. A workaround is to do an additional filtering after receiving the results, but it just doesn't seem to be a good practice.

So ... does anyone knows how to make Facebook Graph API search for **exact** phrase in given language without transliterating it?

Thanks!